# Disable Qty Increment for Admins create orders in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

Current product increment for each product is set to 24, I want to allow admin to create a order from backend without any increment,any qty should be added, but right now it gives error "The fewest you may purchase is 24"

[image]

I have tried to change function get Config qty increment,to disable the qty increment for admin but not worked, sharing code:

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration">
    <plugin name="custom_get_QtyIncrement" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\QtyIncrement" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Vendor/Module/Plugin/QtyIncrement.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;

class QtyIncrement
{

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $_backendSession;

    public function __construct(
        BackendSession $backendSession
    )
    {
        $this->_backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    public function afterGetEnableQtyIncrements(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->_backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $result = 0;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom plugin and override this file

> IsCorrectQtyCondition.php

Folder path:

> /vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition

```
if($adminSession->isLoggedIn()) { //added to remove the validation for order created from admin

}else{

    if ($this->isMinSaleQuantityCheckFailed($stockItemConfiguration, $requestedQty)) {
        return $this->createErrorResult(
            'is_correct_qty-min_sale_qty',
            __(
                'The fewest you may purchase is %1',
                $stockItemConfiguration->getMinSaleQty()
            )
        );
    } 

    if ($this->isMaxSaleQuantityCheckFailed($stockItemConfiguration, $requestedQty)) {
        return $this->createErrorResult(
            'is_correct_qty-max_sale_qty',
            __('The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart')
        );
    }

    
    if ($this->isQuantityIncrementCheckFailed($stockItemConfiguration, $requestedQty)) {
        return $this->createErrorResult(
            'is_correct_qty-qty_increment',
            __(
                'You acan buy this product only in quantities of %1 at a time.',
                $stockItemConfiguration->getQtyIncrements()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

I have used admin session check,to remove the validation for order created from backend.